# UIImageView doesn't move

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview

Just silly thing.

I placed UIImageView in the left top corner. Then make a new outlet

```
@IBOutlet var rocket : UIImageView
```

In the method ViewDidLoad I try to move this UIImageView with different properties but it doesn't

```
rocket.image = UIImage(named: "rocket.png")
rocket.frame = CGRectMake(200,200,200,200)
rocket.bounds = CGRectMake(200,200,200,200)
rocket.center = CGPointMake(400,400)
```

When I start the program an image in the UIImageView appears in the top left corner without any translation.

Comment: If you are using Autolayout the to move UIImageView you should change layout constraints. If not, then try to place this code in viewDidAppear

Comment: thanks, autolayout was on, disable and it helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you did not disables AutoLayout for your viewcontroller which is having that image.

please disable your Viewcontroller's AutoLayout property and change your code with following values so you can able to see the transformed image.

```
[rocket setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200)];
rocket.bounds = CGRectMake(200,200,200,200);
rocket.center = CGPointMake(200,200);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
        rocket.image = UIImage(named: "rocket.png")
        rocket.frame = CGRectMake(200,200,200,200)
        rocket.bounds = CGRectMake(200,200,200,200)
        rocket.center = CGPointMake(400,400)
}];
```

Comment: The matter is that for this program I should not use an animation, i just need to move it when timer fires